# Too few arguments to function in WooCommerce Email Hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a function in PHP and I want to pass three arguments into it below:

```
function lnz_wc_emails_memberreceipients($headers, $object, $order) {

$company = $order->billing_company;

$emailreturn = array (
    'Robin' => "weiltest@weiltest.com",
    'Other' => "beistest@beistest.com, beistest2@beistest.com"
);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Bcc: your name '.$emailreturn[$company];
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html';
return $headers;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'lnz_wc_emails_memberreceipients', 10, 2);
```

However, when I try and do this I get an error which suggests that my function is asking for 3 arguments but is only being passed two.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function lnz_wc_emails_memberreceipients(), 2 passed in /home/benefacto/public_html/dev3/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 300 and exactly 3 expected in /home/benefacto/public_html/dev3/wp-content/plugins/bnfo-custom-emails/bnfo-custom-emails.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /home/benefacto/public_html/dev3/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(300): lnz_wc_emails_memberreceipients('Content-Type: t...', 'customer_comple...') #1 /home/benefacto/public_html/dev3/wp-includes/plugin.php(203): WP_Hook->apply_filters('Content-Type: t...', Array) #2 /home/benefacto/public_html/dev3/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php(287): apply_filters('woocommerce_ema...', 'Content-Type: t...', 'customer_comple...', Object(WC_Order)) #3 /home/benefacto/public_html/dev3/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email-customer-completed-order.php(75): WC_Email->get_headers() #4 /home/benefacto/public_html/dev3/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(298): WC_Email in /home/benefacto/public_html/dev3/wp-content/plugins/bnfo-custom-emails/bnfo-custom-emails.php on line 17
```

If I remove either $object OR $order it works just fine! But if I try and include both it throws the wobbly.

Is there anything I can do to pass it all three? Any thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'lnz_wc_emails_memberreceipients', 10, 2);
```

With

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'lnz_wc_emails_memberreceipients', 10, 3);
```

which accepts 3 arguments for the filter `woocommerce_email_headers`